# Changing CSS styling of individual columns in a Javascript-generated table

Tags: javascript, css

I have created a table to display JSON data via a for loop in a function.  Because I have created the table this way, it has no ID/Class.

I have hidden the last three columns of the table in CSS via the following method, where (n) is the column number:

```
#divIdName table tr td:nth-child(n) { 
display: none; }

#divIdName table th:nth-child(n) { 
display: none; }
```

I am trying to display them via three javascript functions, using queryselector but directly coping the CSS i.e.

```
function showColumnN () {
    if (ArrayName.indexOf("StringName")>-1) {
        var colNd = document.querySelector("td:nth-child(n)");
        var colNh = document.querySelector("th:nth-child(n)");
        colNd.style.display = "block";
        colNh.style.display = "block"; }
```

However only one of the hidden columns is displayed, and it contains just the three headings (one on top of another) and first row data (one on top of another) from each of the three.

Does anyone know where I'm going wrong and how I can get the full columns to display?

EDIT: I omitted that there was a conditional in the showColumnN function, to check whether a particular string is in a particular array and proceed with the column unveiling if this were so.

Comment: Please show all of the relevant code, including the HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: Apologies.  I'm very new to Javascript, and web dev in general, just recently started studying it.  The code is very long and I wasn't sure what would count as totally relevant and what not.  I have seen people here berated heavily for pasted too much 'irrelevant' code, so I tried to be as concise as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However only one of the hidden columns is displayed

That's because you've only selected the **first** `td` and `th` matching those selectors, but there are (presumably) multiple `td`s that match (one per row).

To keep going the way you're going (but **don't**, keep reading), you'd need to loop through those:

```
function showColumnN(n) {
    showAll(document.querySelectorAll("td:nth-child(" + n + ")"));
    showAll(document.querySelectorAll("th:nth-child(" + n + ")"));
}
function showAll(list) {
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(list, function(element) {
        element.style.display = "block";
    });
}
```

**However**, I'd probably use a CSS solution instead where you could add classes to the table that would show those columns:

```
table.show1 tr > th:nth-child(1), table.show1 tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    display: block;
}
table.show2 tr > th:nth-child(2), table.show2 tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    display: block;
}
```

...and so on. Then showing column 2 (for instance) is:

```
document.querySelector("selector-for-the-table").classList.add("show2");
```

(Or better yet, use `hideX` classes that hide them, and only add those as appropriate. Then you don't have to do the `block` thing.)

---

Side note: The default `display` for `td` and `th` isn't `block`, it's `table-cell`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and help!  I tried the first one but get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'display' of undefined" when I try (having replaced the n associated with nth-child in querySelectorAll with the number of the column in question.  I omitted the fact there is a conditional in the ShowColumnN function - would this make a difference?  I haven't tried your CSS version of adding Classes as the table is created via a 'for loop' in a function, and I don't think I can add a Class to able created this way (or at least don't know how).

Comment: @IanF: I confused my looping functions. Fixed above.

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I've been pulling my hair out over this for ages.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var table=document.getElementById("divIdName");
var rows=table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
rows.forEach((row)=>{
  elems=row.getElementsByTagName("td");
 for(i=0;i<4;i++){
 elems[elems.length-4+i].style.display="block";
 }
 });
```

However T. J. Crowders answer is much shorter...

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I haven't tried it out as TJ's worked for me, but it's an interesting solution and one that makes sense even to a complete novice like me.